# KL divergence between a gamma distribution and a lognormal distribution?

Tags: distributions, expected-value, gamma-distribution, lognormal-distribution, kullback-leibler

Is there a **closed-form** formula for the following *KL divergence*?

$D_{KL}(X,Y)$

where

$X \sim \mathrm{Gamma}(k,\theta)$

and

$Y \sim \mathrm{LogNormal}(\mu,\sigma^2)$

Comment: A lot of such results can be found here:  http://www.mast.queensu.ca/~linder/pdf/GiAlLi13.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given: Let our $\text{Gamma}(k,\theta)$ random variable have pdf $f(x)$:

[image]

and let our $\text{Lognormal}(\mu, \sigma)$ random variable have pdf $g(x)$:

[image]

Then, the Kullback-Leibler divergence between the true distribution $f$ and the Lognormal approximation $g$ is given by:

$$E_f\big[\log f(x)\big] - E_f\big[\log g(x)\big]$$

The first term $E_f\big[\log f(x)\big]$ is:

[image]

and the second term $E_f\big[\log g(x)\big]$ is:

[image]

The solution is $P-Q$.

**Notes:**

1. The `Expect` function is from the *mathStatica* package for *Mathematica*.
2. `PolyGamma[n,z]` denotes the $n^{th}$ derivative of the digamma function $\psi(z)=\frac{\Gamma'(z)}{\Gamma(z)}$

Comment: This is great! Thanks a lot. I'll have to start using Mathematica more regularly.

Comment: This seems to be a numeric approximation, not a closed form. Correct? I have read that a closed form for KL divergence exists only for Gaussians or mixtures of Gaussians.

Comment: It is _not_ a numeric approximation. As to the definition of what a closed-form is, ... that is always open for discussion, ... but I think most would agree that the log and digamma functions constitute closed forms.

Comment: @wolfies: Thank you for clarification. Additionally, I've just read an information that KL divergence closed forms exist not only for Gaussians or mixtures of Gaussians, but also for some other distributions, such as Beta.

Comment: +1 I didn't have to read past the second line to know whose answer this was.

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh It should be trivially true that KL divergence exists for other distributions: for example, KL divergence with the uniform distribution becomes the entropy. Also, I don't actually think it's true that a closed form exists for mixtures of Gaissians.

Comment: @Dougal: I wasn't talking about just KL divergence, but its *closed form*, which exists only for **some** distributions. In regard to your second point, you're right - I was thinking about a related to KL divergence measure - _Jensen-Rényi divergence_. So, for a JR divergence, a closed form does exist: see [this paper](https://www.cise.ufl.edu/~anand/pdf/jr-miccai09-final.pdf).

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh Yes, I also meant the closed form and should have said that. My example was that the divergence from a uniform is the entropy of the first distribution, so any distribution with a closed-form entropy has at least one set of closed-form KL divergences. And it's important to note that the closed-form JR divergence for GMMs only exists for parameter alpha=2 (the quadratic entropy), not for all JR divergences. (Indeed, the KL is a limit case of the JR divergence as alpha goes to 1.)

Comment: @Dougal: Thank you for clarification - I see this now, browsing the paper again. BTW, if you're interested, I ran across an [interesting paper](http://www.sonycsl.co.jp/person/nielsen/CauchySchwarzDivergence-ICPR2012_accepted.pdf), discussing and specifying sufficient conditions for a probability distribution family for a mixture of two of such distributions to have a closed form for some non-KL divergence measures, including JR.

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh Interesting, thanks for the pointer!

Comment: @Dougal: You're quite welcome!